# Smallest "Unprovable" Cardinal?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

Assuming the existence of a worldly cardinal in $V$, what is the smallest cardinal in $V$ not in every transitive $\mathcal{M}$ such that $\mathcal{M}\models\mathrm{ZFC}$ and is a substructure of $\langle V,\in\rangle$?

What about the smallest ordinal such that the previous question holds?

Are either of these questions known?

This will possibly be my last set theory question for a while.

Comment: The empty set is a substructure of $\langle V,\in\rangle$...I think you want to require something stronger than just "substructure".

Comment: Wow I totally failed to state what I was actually trying to say. I have edited the question accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Presumably you also want to require $\mathcal{M}$ to be transitive; otherwise there's no set that is required to be in $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry, its just really late where I live, I'm kind of tired. I appreciate the help though

Comment: How do you parse the statement "$\mathcal M\models\mathrm{ZFC}$ is a substructure of $\langle V,\in\rangle$"?

Comment: $\omega_1$ (the one from V) doesn't even need to be in $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: "$\mathcal M$ is a model of $\mathrm ZFC$ is a substructure of $\langle V,\in\rangle$" does not really make grammatical sense in English. Maybe you left out an "and"?

Comment: Every set is a substructure of $V$.

Comment: Yes but proper classes are too

Comment: Actually I didn't want it to be transitive because $\omega$ is guaranteed by the axiom of infinity

Answer (score 6):

It isn't clear to me what you mean when you say that $\mathcal{M}$ is a substructure of $V$, so I will assume that you are just interested in transitive $\mathcal{M}$ in general.

As Jonathan says in the comments, $\omega_1$ is the least cardinal ommited from a transitive $\mathcal{M}$. This is because, if there are any transitive models of ZFC at all, then there are countable ones and $\omega_1$ cannot be an element of a countable transitive model.

The least such ordinal, call it $\alpha$, is countable and is usually described as the height of the least transitive model of ZFC. In other words, it is the least ordinal such that $L_\alpha$ is a model of ZFC. This ordinal is clearly ommited from some transitive model (e.g. $L_\alpha$ itself, by definition), and every smaller ordinal is contained in every transitive model (again, by definition, since $L_\alpha$ is contained in all those models).

Comment: Well then ZFC can't even prove $\beth_1$

Comment: ZFC proves $\beth_1$ exists but different models have different ordinals which they believe to be $\beth_1.$ In countable transtive models $M$ of ZFC, $\beth_1^V \not \in M,$ while $\beth_1^M$ is a countable ordinal of $V.$